# Start functions when bootstrap carousel-selector has class selected

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

The following functions shows counting numbers. Its within a bootstrap carousel.

I want to start this function, when the bootstrap carousel-selector has `class="selected"` and not immediately on pageload.

AND 2nd condition should be that the user really is on that part of page (`#video`). So the function does not start when he does not see the function related part (maybe via scrollspy somehow?). How can I do this?

```
$('.count').each(function () {
    $(this).prop('Counter',0).animate({
        Counter: $(this).text()
    }, {
        duration: 4000,
        easing: 'swing',
        step: function (now) {
            $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
        }
    });
});
```

Question is regarding this page (last slide): https://bm-translations.de/km#video

[image]

Comment: Can you explain more `before AND if the user really is on that part of page`?

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: Can you give us an example of your html code in jsfiddle (or any other platform) ? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First condition:
Check if Carousell has Class

```
if $('#yourcaroussellID').hasClass('selected')
```

Second condition
Compare users position on page to the elements position on page

```
isInViewport = function() {
    var videoTop = $('#carouselMarketing1').offset().top;
    var videoBottom = videoTop + $('#carouselMarketing1').outerHeight();

    var viewportTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height();

    return videoBottom > viewportTop && videoTop < viewportBottom;
}
```

You will need to check the combined ifs at an interval to see the changes in scrolling:

```
myInterval = setInterval(function(){ 
    if ($('#carousel-selector-4').hasClass('selected') && (isInViewport())) { 
        yourCounter();
        myStopFunction();
    }
}, 1000);
```

Make your counter a function you can call:

```
yourCounter = function() {
    $('.count').each(function () {
        $(this).prop('Counter',0).animate({
            Counter: $(this).text()
        }, {
            duration: 4000,
            easing: 'swing',
            step: function (now) {
                $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Make a stop function for the interval:

```
function myStopFunction() {
    clearInterval(myInterval );
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but it wasnt working:

var usertop = $('html').offset().top;
var videotop = $('#carouselMarketing1').offset().top;
$('#carouselMarketing1').on('slide.bs.carousel', function() {
  if ($('#carousel-selector-4').hasClass('selected') && (usertop >= videotop)) {
          $('.count').each(function () {
    $(this).prop('Counter',0).animate({
        Counter: $(this).text()
    }, {
        duration: 4000,
        easing: 'swing',
        step: function (now) {
            $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
        }
    });
});
        }
});

Comment: Check this fiddle, it might help you out: https://jsfiddle.net/7fheh60x/, I also adjusted the code a bit to give you more of a ready solution than just the steps themselves.

Comment: now its counting forward and backward again and again. I guess its cause of the intervall?

Comment: You should move your counter to a function, and call this function after you determined the user is looking at the video, then clear the interval: like this: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp. If you put the counter in the interval it will start again each interval step otherwise.

Comment: @KrystianManthey I added an example for clear interval to my post and also this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7fheh60x/1/